# Organizing FamilySearch Sources in Gramps

Tags: gramps, familysearch.org, citation

I'm trying to get started with Gramps and am having trouble figuring out the right way to model references to Family Search as sources/citations.

I tried to follow the model from [this email thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/gramps/mailman/message/29962663/), but it seems to result in my sources and citations essentially duplicating each other.

I'm thinking about switching to the following (example below) and was wondering if a) it makes sense and b) what other people do.

```
Repository: Family Search
Source: Illinois, County Marriages, 1810-1840 (link to the main familysearch page)
Citation (one for each marriage): The particular image with link, FHC film numbers, etc
```

Answer (score 3):

I do as you described in your example. Also I link the event to the citation. This is a lot of clicks in the UI but it helps a lot when you come back two years later to continue your research. I wish I had known that sources were SO important when I started genealogy.

Comment: *So* many windows and so many clicks. Especially because I decided to put the FHL film details as "attributes". But maybe I can figure out how to make gramplet to do that with fewer clicks if I keep going with this.

Comment: Also, if you have ideas on how to make the UI perform with less clicks, make sure to raise a feature request on the bug tracker site here: https://gramps-project.org/bugs/my_view_page.php or if you don't,  just raise an issue explaining how painful the data entry is (it will help to raise the awareness of the devs on the UX topic).

Comment: @hoyland if you're doing a lot of clicking in Gramps, you're doing something inefficiently.

Comment: @RonJohn " if you're doing a lot of clicking in Gramps, you're doing something inefficiently" you're joking right? I do love gramps but it is a real click machine if you record things properly (ie. source based vs person based)

Comment: Sadly, "a lot" is relative, so my "relatively few" might be your "lot".  I can, though, say with all absoluteness, that I #1 click and type **a whole lot less** now when using the clipboard than before using the clipboard, and #2 subsequently use citations as evidence for a **lot** more events.

Comment: Just as importantly, "find some evidence, create a citation, and then add the people, families, events, places, etc which flow from that evidence (or add this as more proof of existing objects)" works just fine for me.  Your absolutist judgement is not wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar to Option #2, but don't even use a Repository, since these electronic records are on so many web sites.

Thus:

*Source*: Oregon, Yamhill County, Index to Marriage Records

*Citation*: Year: YYYY / Volume<sup>*</sup>: NNNN / Page: XXX

Attach it to the Family object who's marriage you're proving, and then drag it to the clipboard.  From there I drag the citation to whatever other object is relevant to the citation.  (For marriage licenses, it's usually just the wedding, but their info can also generate Occupation events, birth events, Residence, events etc, and that one citation is evidence for all those events.)

<sup>*</sup>Some states call it "Volume", some call it "Book".  I follow that state's nomenclature for that state's citations.

Comment: What is Option #2 that you refer to? Can you please make your answer self-contained?